# Why an NSException error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsexception

I have put the following code in...;

```
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
@"Hello,\n You've just received a new message from the iDHSB iPhone App.\n Here it is: %@",field.text,     
kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

...and I receive an NSException error saying;

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate:     
<NSInvalidArgumentException> +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did  
you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?
```

What does this mean? What do I have to do to fix this issue?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to format a string in your dictionary initialization and it expects the format to be `object, key, object, key, etc..`. To fix try creating your formatted string on another line for clarity and then adding it as part of the objects and keys as so

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello,\n You've just received a new message from the iDHSB iPhone App.\n Here it is: %@",
                                                 field.text];
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"text/plain", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                              message, kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
                              @"8bit", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you meant something like this:

```
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello,\n You've just received a new message from the iDHSB iPhone App.\n Here it is: %@",field.text], kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey, @"8bit", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

Comment: done this and it works, thanks! But when it sends the email (because that's what it does), it just says ... Here it is: and then nothing, when it should add the text from the UITextField... Here's the code I used... http://pastie.org/2504653 I declared "messagebody" here: http://pastie.org/2504667.

Comment: Check out that you have declared messagebody before you are initialising *plainpart NSDictionary. Or you need to use NSMutableDictionary if it mutates(changes) after initialising.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an argument. I count 8 total arguments including nil. That means one of your key value pairs is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try firsty create string:

```
NSString *partMessageKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello,\n You've just received a new message from the iDHSB iPhone App.\n Here it is: %@",field.text];
```

then put this string to dictionary as object.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds silly but how would I "put this string to dictionary as object"? :-)